# Нужно ли удалять ветку после слияния её с другой?

Tags: git, git-branch

В проекте есть ветка `master`. От нее ответвлена `dev`, а от dev идут ветки отдельных фиксов, назовем `fix`.
Т.е. проект выглядит как `master -> dev -> fix`. После объединения веток `dev` и `fix`, в репозитории сохранилась ветка `fix`.

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
<<тут изменения при слиянии>>
git branch
> fix
>*dev
> master
```

Надо ли ее удалять или она так и должна висеть там?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Можно вполне спокойно удалить. Многие так и делают, что бы просто не мозолило глаза в списке веток.

Тем не менее, это совершенно не обязательно - если не хотите, можете и оставить.

Ну и естественно не стоит удалять постоянные ветки, которые в команде условлено использовать для постоянного процесса разработки, например созданные для соответствия тому-же [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). Т.е. если вы скажем, влили ветку develop в master, закончив работу над некой функциональностью, то постоянно удалять ветвь develop после слияния - крайне глупая затея.

Answer (score 3):

В большинстве случаев, после слияния можно безопасно удалить отработанную ветку

```
git branch -d имяВетки
```

В случае если git посчитает что ветка не была полностью слита, он покажет предупреждение и откажется удалять ветвь. Если вы уверены что нужно удалить ветвь (используя `git branch -D имяВетки`) которая еще не полностью объединена, вам нужно сделать несколько дополнительных действий чтобы привести в порядок необъединенные коммиты.

Есть ряд случаев когда ветвь рекомендуется сохранить. Например, если это ветка новых возможностей (новых фич), то возможно вы захотите делать правки этой возможности (фичи) внутри объединенной ветки.

> Это перевод ответа Jonas Wielicki https://stackoverflow.com/a/14005910

Comment: Джонас Велицкий в своём ответе не писал что рекомендуется. Решение удалять или не удалять - полностью зависит от договоренности об процессе разработке в вашей команде.

Comment: "it's safe to delete the branch" - не "рекомендуется", а "можно, безопасно"

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, перевод поправил

Comment: @atom-22 а вообще хорошо получилось, переводите еще.