# Удаление старых веток?

Tags: git

Нужно ли удалять старые неиспользуемые ветки (origin) в git?
Или если их оставить то будет какой то плюс? Поиск быстрее идти или еще что то полезное?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется что от лишнего быстрее ничего не станет :)

Comment: Просто после того, как они стали неиспользуемыми (т.е. завершен merge или pull request) смысла их хранить нет

Comment: Похожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428881

Comment: Удаляю старые. Меньше бардака. Но если релиз делаю то создаю бэкапную ветку.  Если стабильных релизов более 3-х то самую старую бэкапную ветку тоже удаляю. Когда много веток по разным таскам - начинаю забывать что на какой ветке делал. По прошествии пары недель - сложно ориентироваться на каких ветках таски готовы и ждут добро на мердж,  а на каких отложена работа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно ли удалять старые неиспользуемые ветки (origin) в git?

В GitLab (не заню как в других web-интерфейсах, возможно так же) при создании merge-request можно сразу указать, что ветка будет автоматически удалена после успешного слияния. Так что это частая модель поведения.

> Или если их оставить то будет какой то плюс?

Плюс в том, что у вас будет информация о том, что это была за ветка. Если у вас в проекте нет соглашения об именовании веток или есть соглашение о комментариях к коммитам (особенно merge-коммитам), то эта информация вам не особо нужна.

> Поиск быстрее идти или еще что то полезное?

Единственная польза - уменьшение количества визуального мусора. Быстрее идет поиск глазами. Если в проекте 10 тысяч коммитов и тысяча "мертывх" веток, то найти 2-3 нужных ветки - серьезная проблема.

Comment: *git branch --list ...* вам в помощь (к последнему предложению).

Answer (score 2):

Если ветку слили с другой веткой и работа в ней не планирует, то можно смело её удалить. Тем более что в любой момент можно создать ветку в любом месте дерева

Answer (score 2):

ветка и (обычная) метка — это указатель на коммит.

«физически» каждая метка/ветка — это **один** файл размером **41 байт** (40 байт — хэш коммита, ещё один байт — `\n`), находящийся в одном из подкаталогов каталога `refs` в хранилище (хранилище обычно располагается в каталоге `.git`, рядом с рабочей копией файлов).

это, собственно, всё, что «освободится», если такой файл удалить.

---

другое дело, что такое удаление может **косвенно** привести (в процессе [«сборки мусора»](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)) к удалению объектов из хранилища.

типы объектов, которые можно встретить в хранилище *git* (посмотреть тип объекта: `$ git cat-file -t хэш-объекта`):

1. коммиты (*commit*) могут содержать ссылки на

   1. коммиты
   2. деревья
2. деревья (*tree*) могут содержать ссылки на

   1. деревья
   2. блобы
3. блобы (*blob*)
4. аннотированные метки (*tag*) могут содержать ссылки на

   1. коммиты

если на объект нет ни одной ссылки, то при «сборке мусора» он будет удалён, а вслед за ним и те объкты, на которые он ссылался, и на которые нет других ссылок, тоже будут удалены, и так рекурсивно.